# Google chrome on Windows 8 does not understand time format in javascript cookie expiration time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I would like to set a cookie from Javascript for short period of time (some hours). I use the following time format:

```
document.cookie="MYCOOKIE=TEST; expires=Saturday, 28-Jun-14 21:01:33 GMT";
```

This works fine from many browsers, but it seems to be a problem with Google Chrome on Windows.

For example in Google Chrome on Windows 8, after setting the Cookie above, I go to `Settings->Privacy->Content Settings->Cookies and site data` it shows: (I am in CEST time zone, so I am 2 hours ahead of GMT)

```
Expires:    Saturday, June 28, 2014 10:01:33 PM
```

Note that expiration time is `10:01:33 CEST` whereas the correct should be `11:01:33 CEST`.

(This works fine with Chromium browser on Ubuntu 12.04 and Firefox on Windows 8)

See also [Chrome does not allow cookies with expirations less than 4 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889824/chrome-does-not-allow-cookies-with-expirations-less-than-4-hours).

Answer (score 1):

How about trying a cookie library like this: https://github.com/ScottHamper/Cookies.

If you scroll down the page to the examples, there are three different ways to set a cookie's date, and it says it's cross browser, so there is a chance that it has accounted for this strange difference in how Chrome acts on Windows 8.  And, according to the site, it is a tiny 1kb file so it shouldn't noticably slow your page.